# Anyway to debug web projects on AS7(Jboss) with intellij Community Edition

Tags: java, spring, jboss, intellij-idea

Anyway to debug web projects on AS7(Jboss) with intellij Community Edition?

I am looking for a way to debug my spring mvc project in intellij running on jboss AS7

Comment: Does http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/run-debug-configuration-jboss-server.html not help ?

Comment: I dont see anything in that link that shows how to use the community edition with jboss

Answer (score 2):

You can use Remote debug for plain Java code debugging, but you can't debug JSP code at all with the Community Edition.

Comment: Any Java code can be debugged with Remote Debug, including Servlets.